# add drowndown option in officejs fabric UI component

Tags: office-ui-fabric

i am using the following office js fabric component. it seems to be working but i want to add options dynamically instead of design time. i am not able to do that. any code snippet will be helpful.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/dropdown/dropdown
I have tried and successfully able to add options to basic html select control but this one appears to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

I first add the options to the select control with jQuery, and then init the component like the documentation says.

```html
$("#platformId").append('<option value="3">Option 3</option>');
```

Comment: this will work only if you want to add all the options before user has done anything. what if you have to add an option depending on some user activity on some other click or basically after initial load.